# Create data frame based on combination of possible name pairings

Tags: r, combinations

I need to make a data frame with every possible combination of two sets (or groups) of names in such a way that no name from a set is matched with another name from that same set. Then turn this into a data frame.

For example: take:

```
 set_1 = c("n1","n2","n3", "n4")
 set_2 = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4")
```

I know I could use the following to choose x (2 for example below) from either set like

```
data.frame(t(combn(set_1, 2))
```

I could even combine set_1 and set_2 and use that in the combn function but this would not limit the combinations so that say, "n1" cannot be chosen if "n2" (or n3 or n4) are chosen.

Hopefully this explains the problem clearly! Thank you all!

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: `expand.grid(Set_1, set_2)`??

Comment: Sorry. Let's say I want to pick every combo for choosing one from each set. I want two columns with every row being a unique combination of all possible name pairings.

Comment: That is exactly what the code I gave returns

Comment: Awesome! No I was just falling asleep and wanted to answer your question first. Thank you!